# Display parameters in reverse order

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to create a batch file which will display on the screen up to 9 parameters, but displays them in **reverse order**. Name of the batch file is reverse11.bat

```
eg: C:\>REVERSE11.bat a b c d e <enter>
e d c b a REVERSE
```

I tried to do so like this, it kinda mess and didnt work. :(

```
SORT/R < %O > ANSWER
ECHO ANSWER
```

Whats wrong with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SORT` sorts *lines*, not words, so you'll need to put each parameter on its own line.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo %1> unsorted.txt
echo %2>> unsorted.txt
echo %3>> unsorted.txt
:: etc...

sort /r unsorted.txt > sorted.txt
```

At this point you could display sorted.txt if you're okay with them all being on separate lines:

```
type sorted.txt
```

But if you want to get them all back onto a single line you'll have to process the file like this:

```
for /f %%a in (sorted.txt) do (
    set out=!out! %%a
)
echo %out%
```

Comment: NO, SORT/R can sort things in reverse order, I'm doing a tutorial, it says how to sort in reverse order, but in tutorial input is from a file. but in this case in put should be taken as a parameter. C:\>reverse11.bat abcdefg then when pressed enter answer should be gfedcba, that can be done using sort/r but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand your question.  Do you want to sort your parameters *alphabetically* (that's what `SORT` will do) or are you just trying to access them in the reverse order that they were entered?

Comment: its like this - I want to enter an input through parameters ( reverse11.bat ABCDEFG) then parameters should be taken in and sorted in reverse order - final answer should be GFEDCBA

Comment: What if I do this:  `reverse11.bat a c b`.  Should the output be `b c a` (reversing the order I typed them in) or should it be `c b a` (inverse-alphabetical)?

Comment: its should be    Z to A and 9 to 0

Comment: Ok, I've rewritten the answer.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I wanted. that was in my tutorial as I told you but I had no idea how to match things up and make it done.. Thanks a lot @nate :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 1):

You must note that `sort` command Works on LINES, not WORDS! The Batch file below first divide the parameters in separate lines and store they in a temp file; the second part invoke `sort /R` on the file and collect its output lines in just one string:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
(for %%a in (%*) do echo %%a) > temp.txt 
set output=
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('sort /R ^< temp.txt') do set output=!output! %%a
echo %output:~1%
del temp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET reversed=%0
:loop
SET newparam=%1
IF NOT defined newparam ECHO %reversed%&GOTO :eof
SET reversed=%1 %reversed%
shift
GOTO loop
```

We start by setting the variable `reversed` to the value of the program name.

Set `newparam` to the value of the FIRST parameter (%1)
If that parameter exists,add it to the FRONT of the accumulated string, then `SHIFT` to move the parameters to one position lower (%2 becomes %1, %3 becomes %2, etc.) and loop back until...

the `%1` parameter does NOT exist (because they've all been `SHIFT`ed out) so echo the accumulated string in `reversed` and finish the routine.